# laravel form "select field" is not working

Tags: javascript, laravel

Hello I have a problem with "select field" when submitting the form, it tells me that the field is required even though there is already a data selected for it.
[error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxNVj.png)

When I checked the network tab, headers it is showing blank, so there is no data being passed.
[network screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEI9X.png)

I have already declared the year id properly inside a JS. Here's my code:

```
$('#tax-form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let taxdeclarationnumber = $("#tax_declaration_number").val();
    let currentrpt = $("#current_rpt").val();
    let year = $("#year").val();
    console.log('nani poku');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/tax-information",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            tax_declaration_number: taxdeclarationnumber,
            current_rpt: currentrpt,
            year: year,
        },
```

my blade:

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">For the Year</label>
                            <select name="year" id="year" class="custom-select year-list" data-style="btn btn-secondary">
                            </select>
                        </div>
```

I'm using a separate JS for this select field, this is to generate a dynamic year list.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    for (var i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
        // var option = "<option value=" + parseInt(d.getFullYear() + i) + ">" + parseInt(d.getFullYear() + i) + "</option>"
        var option = '<option value="' + parseInt(d.getFullYear() + i) + '">' + parseInt(d.getFullYear() + i) + "</option>"
        $('[id*=year]').append(option);
    }
});
```

What other steps I need to do here? I'm pretty sure there is no issue with my controller.

Comment: try   let year = $("#year :selected").val();

Comment: it won't work, any suggestions?

Comment: first alert(year) whether it has value or not